# cleaned message, which contains only letters a-z, and numbers 0-9 with only one space

Tags: python

cleaned message, which contains only letters a-z, and numbers 0-9, with only one space between words

```
def clean_data(message):
    return " ".join("".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]", message)).lower().split())

sentence_1 = 'Doesn\'t get, how{to}% \\operate+66.7 :after[it]"" & lt;# & gt; won\'t `or(what)'
sentence_2 = 'O\]k,.lar7i$double{} check wif*& da! hair: [dresser;   ..already He SaID-77.88.5 wun cut v short question(std txt rate)T&C\'s'
```

```
cleaned:  doesnt get howto operate667 afterit lt gt wont orwhat
cleaned:  oklar7idouble check wif da hair dresser already he said77885 wun cut v short questionstd txt ratetcs
```

Expected Output:

```
cleaned:    doesn t get how to operate 66 7 after it lt gt won t or what
cleaned:    o k lar7i double check wif da hair dresser already he said 77 88 5 wun cut v short question std txt rate t c s
```

Comment: Why are you expecting `'` and `.` to be replaced by space?

Comment: You're missing the part where you replace anything that is not `[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]` with a space. `re.sub` can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have posted we can deduce a couple of things:

- Output should have alphanumeric characters only
- Everything that wasn't an alphanumeric character get's replaced with a whitespace
- We shouldn't have multiple spaces next to each other
- Output is lowercase only

Assuming that's the expected behavior, the code is very straight forward:

```
def clean_data(message):
    return re.sub(r"[^\w]+", " ", message).lower()
```

1. You're getting chunks of unwanted characters with `[^\w]+` and replacing them with a singular whitespace with the help of [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).
2. We convert everything to lowercase with [`.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower)

---

```
sentence_1 = 'Doesn\'t get, how{to}% \\operate+66.7 :after[it]"" & lt;# & gt; won\'t `or(what)'
sentence_2 = 'O\]k,.lar7i$double{} check wif*& da! hair: [dresser;   ..already He SaID-77.88.5 wun cut v short question(std txt rate)T&C\'s'

print(clean_data(sentence_1))
print(clean_data(sentence_2))

>>> doesn t get how to operate 66 7 after it lt gt won t or what 
>>> o k lar7i double check wif da hair dresser already he said 77 88 5 wun cut v short question std txt rate t c s
```